# Netbeans getting stuck while opening existing project

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-8, nette

I am using Netbeans 8.2 and JDK 8.0 and I am trying to open project (PHP) cloned from Sourcetree but I am getting stuck at 10%. Also when I TO try open it as new project with existing resources I get stuck on 40%.

Opening new empty project work fine, also opening files from the cloned project works fine. I tried to reinstal Netbeans, restart computer, run as administrator but nothing helped.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: More suited for https://netbeans.org/community/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by downloading new clone of the project. The first one was probably broken.